# Associated account is empty and I have 2 meta accounts!

Tags: support, user-accounts, linked-accounts, multiple-accounts

See the screenshot below. You can see 2 `meta` accounts and no SO or any other associated account of mine.

[image]

And this is snapshot of my **StackoverFlow Account**

[image]

Question: My account has undergone lot of issues lately, like de-merger, closing of some duplicate accounts, etc. Is this issue related to that or is there some other problem?

Comment: Do you have a link to your Stack Overflow profile still?

Comment: yes.. => http://stackoverflow.com/users/3154233/noobeditor and all other linked accounts are still showing and working on that!!!

Comment: @MartijnPieters And this : http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/242549/noobeditor

Comment: Check, looks like a bug with the Meta account only then. You still use the same login for the Meta account, right?

Comment: @loxxy: that we can get from clicking on the OP usercard on this question. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters right... my bad :p I thought I found the other profile. Didn't care to check.

Comment: @MartijnPieters : yes...i go to SO, then in url, i add `meta` before SO and this account of mine opens up!!

Comment: @MartijnPieters : the account with `Rep 1` is bad account, i cannot even edit its `about me` so that it can be deleted...basically, its like a dead account linked to mine...because when u open it open, you'll see a `unique-id` instead of a name and some other linked meta account, not this one!!

Comment: Something is a little wonky with your account, I'm asking a developer to take a look now.